# Probability formulas

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Is there a mathematical formula to calculate the number of combinations possible when making 7 sets of three out of 7 choices, where the order does not matter and no two of the choices are ever together twice? I believe the answer is one but is there a formula that shows this?

*Edit:
I see that my question was unclear. Let me put it like this: I have seven letters, A,B,C,D,E,F,G. I want to make seven pairs of three letters. Each letter is with each other letter exactly one time. We can have ABC,ADE,and AFG as sets but not ABC and ABD because then A and B are in the same set twice. How many possible combinations can I make? I believe the answer is seven, but is there a formula to calculate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you mean is you want the number of unordered $7$-tuples $(S_1, \ldots, S_7)$ where each $S_i$ is a subset of $\{1,\ldots, 7\}$ with cardinality $3$, and each intersection $S_i \cap S_j$ has cardinality at most $1$.  Enumerate the ${7 \choose 3} = 35$ subsets of $\{1,\ldots,7\}$ with cardinality $3$ as $T_1,\ldots,T_{35}$.  Form the graph $G$ with $35$ vertices and an edge $\{i,j\}$ if $|T_i \cap T_j| \le 1$.  Then we want to count all $7$-cliques in this graph.
I don't think this is easy to do.  But the answer is certainly more than $1$.
One possible $7$-clique corresponds to the $7$ sets
$$ [ \left\{ 1,2,3 \right\} , \left\{ 1,4,5 \right\} , \left\{ 1,6,7
 \right\} , \left\{ 2,4,6 \right\} , \left\{ 2,5,7 \right\} , \left\{ 
3,4,7 \right\} , \left\{ 3,5,6 \right\} ]
$$
But for any permutation $\pi$ of $\{1,\ldots, 7\}$, we get another $7$-clique by replacing each $i$ by $\pi(i)$.  In many cases this will give us a different $7$-clique.  For example, interchanging $1$ and $2$ gives us another $7$-clique corresponding to the sets
$$ [ \left\{ 1,2,3 \right\} , \left\{ 2,4,5 \right\} , \left\{ 2,6,7
 \right\} , \left\{ 1,4,6 \right\} , \left\{ 1,5,7 \right\} , \left\{ 
3,4,7 \right\} , \left\{ 3,5,6 \right\} ]$$
In fact using permutations we get  $30$ such $7$-cliques.  I don't know whether those are all the possible $7$-cliques.